# How to fix my string concatenation that isn't working?

Tags: reactjs, string, react-native

I am trying to display a star map using [this API](https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude=77.102493&latitude=28.704060&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true) to display a star map. If you look at the hyperlink, there is two parts that says longitude={number}&latitude={number}. I decided that I want to take in user longitude and latitude from the  component and set the latitude and longitude accordingly. I got the longitude and latitude, but I can't get the string to concatenate(I will explain now)

To show this starMap, I used the  component. I made a variable called path which is the API link with my user inputed latitude and longitude, but the  just wouldn't update. I tried printing out my latitude and longitude, and they were regular integers. When I printed out path, it said that longitude= [Object object]&latitude = [Object object].

I will send my code, GitHub repo link, and console output

GitHub repo: [repo link](https://github.com/ryankim0709/stellar.git)

code: const path is the line you want to look at by the way

````js
import React from 'react'
import { View,Dimensions, Text, Platform, StatusBar, TouchableWithoutFeedback, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Keyboard } from 'react-native'
import {Header} from 'react-native-elements'
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview'

export default class StarMapScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      longitude: 100,
      latitude: 0,
      //path: "https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude=0&latitude=0&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true"
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {longitude, latitude} = this.state
    console.log(longitude)
    console.log(latitude)
    const path = 'https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude='+{longitude}+'&latitude='+{latitude}+'&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true'
    console.log(path)
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior  = {Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} style = {{flex:1,alignItems:'center'}}>
        
          
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress = {Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
              <View>
                <TextInput 
                  multiline = {true}
                  style = {styles.inputBox}
                  placeholder = "Latitude"
                  onChangeText = {text => {
                    this.setState({latitude:text})}}/>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback  onPress = {Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
              <View>
                <TextInput 
                  multiline = {true}
                  style = {styles.inputBox}
                  placeholder = "Longitude"
                  onChangeText = {text => {
                    this.setState({longitude:text})}}/>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          
          <WebView 
            style={{marginTop:20, marginBottom:20, width:Dimensions.get('window').width}}
            //scalesPageToFit = {true}
            source={{ uri: path}}/>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  droidSafeArea: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0
  },
  inputView: {
    backgroundColor:"#480ca8",
    alignItems:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
  starText: {
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'white',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize:20
  },
  inputBox: {
    width:400,
    height:40,
    borderColor:'white',
    borderRadius:30,
    borderWidth:2,
    justifyContent:'center',
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'white',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize:20,
    marginTop:10
    
  }
})```
````

Here are the console.logs outputted

```
https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude${longitude}=&latitude${latitude}=&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true
100
0
https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude=[object Object]&latitude=[object Object]&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true
100
1
https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude=[object Object]&latitude=[object Object]&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true
100
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for string concatenation is incorrect. You are contacting string with object.

```
{longitude} means {longitude : longitude}
```

There are multiple ways to fix this issue

Solution 1:-

```
const path = 'https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude='+longitude+'&latitude='+latitude+'&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true'
```

Solution 2:-

```
const path = `https://virtualsky.lco.global/embed/index.html?longitude=${longitude}&latitude=${latitude}&constellations=true&constellationlabels=true&showstarlabels=true&gridlines_az=true&live=true`
```